# What's the best way to draw a pie chart in Android with selectable slices?

Tags: android, charts

I've looked into achartengine and a couple other options, but none of them seem to support any way to implement drill down into the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but with histograms. I ended up creating a custom view that:

- takes a maximum value as the top of the graph, to make a proportion with values to graph (you have 360 constant degrees)
- an array of values
- a parameter for column width

then draws the histogram (it won't be too hard drawing a pie chart) and overriding `onTouchEvent()` to determine which column was clicked.

As we're talking of a pie chart you'll have to do some more maths to find which slice was clicked.